# Traduction de "tient à ce qu'elle touche ..."

Tags: traduction

De ce [site](https://www.franceculture.fr/emissions/la-compagnie-des-auteurs/jules-verne-24-les-voyages-de-jules-verne):

> L'influence durable de l’œuvre de Jules Verne tient à ce qu'elle touche à la part d'enfance de chaque homme.

Comment traduirait-on cette phrase ? J'ai de la difficulté avec la partie "tient à ce qu'elle touche". Peut-on la traiter comme "est qu'elle touche" et traduire la phrase par:

> The durable influence of Jules Verne's work is that it touches the childhood of every man.

Comment: Ce n'est pas une question à propos de la langue française. Si c'est le sens du français qui pose problème, reformuler la question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lasting influence of Jules Verne's work lies in the fact that it touches every man's childhood share.